# Can't find the closest label with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I can't find the closest label with Jquery.

The id of the label is different with the id of the input :

```js
$(document).delegate("input[type=text]", "keyup", function() {

  if (this.className == 'other-val') {

    $label = $('label[for="' + this.id + '"]');

    if ($label.length > 0) {
      console.log('ok')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="radio-group-1548153603981-other">Other
    <input type="text" id="radio-group-1548153603981-other-value" class="other-val user-success" style="display: inline-block;">
    </label>
```

Hope someone could help me

Comment: replace `$('label[for="'+ this.id +'"]');` with this `$("label[for='"+ this.id +"']");`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but still false

Comment: @Ahtisham: Why should the type of quotes matter?

Comment: you need to use `hasClass`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have multiple classname for this element, you have to use `includes` instead of `=` operator.

Also the ID of input is `radio-group-1548153603981-other-value` and you missed word `value` in label and as your HTML is generated by third party software, so I use `.replace` to omit the **-value** from input id.

```js
$(document).delegate( "input[type=text]", "keyup", function() {

        if(this.className.includes('other-val')){

            $label = $('label[for="'+ this.id.replace("-value","") +'"]');

            if ($label.length > 0 ) {
                console.log('ok')
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="radio-group-1548153603981-other">Other
<input type="text" id="radio-group-1548153603981-other-value" class="other-val user-success" style="display: inline-block;">
</label>
```

Comment: I can't modifiy the for content in the label. this HTML is generated by formBuilderJs

Comment: I have added a suggestion at the end of answer to solve the html problem.@MathieuMourareau

Comment: if i do this.id.replace("value","") i will replace the id of the input right ?

Comment: How can i remove only "-value" in the id ? actualy when i do console.log(this.id) i get : radio-group-1548153603981-other-value i would like to replace with radio-group-1548153603981-other

Comment: I have edited the answer again according to new questions in comments @MathieuMourareau

Answer (score 1):

Use `on` instead of `delegate`, use most jQuery features, don't combine pure DOM javascript if you use jQuery.

I see that label is parent for `input`, so use [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

```
$(document).on( "keyup", "input[type='text']", function() {

   if($(this).hasClass('other-val')) {
        $label = $(this).closest("label"); 

        if ($label.length > 0 ) {
            console.log('ok')
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<label for="radio-group-1548153603981-other">
```

Possible ways to fetch above label using jquery.

1. `$('label[for$=other]');`  -  "$=" ignores all the text before "other" and find  the control
2. `$(this).siblings('label[for$=other]');` - when within callback function of any of its sibling element.
3. `$('label[for=radio-group-1548153603981-other]')`

Answer (score 0):

your markup is a little bit confusing me. try this:

sample for HTML Markup:

```
<div>
  <label>some text</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Jquery Selector:

```
let $input = $('input[type="text"]');
let $label = $input.parent().find('label');
```

a lable has not to surround the input field

Comment: I can't modifiy the HTML. i have a formBuilder js who construct all the html.